# Webform component weight within a Fieldset

Tags: 6, webforms, database

I am creating a settings page for a specific Webform in version 6.x-3.x which finds all select option components in the form and creates a numeric textfield setting correlating to each select option. The Select Options are in fieldsets. On the settings page, I want the numeric textfields to show up in the same order that the select options show up in the form.

db_querying the right select options in the `webform_component` table is working fine, but the select options show up out of order when ordering by `weight`.

For example:

The Webform

```
Fieldset 1
- Textfield 1
- Select Option 1
- Select Option 2
Fieldset 2
- Select Option 3
- Select Option 4
```

`db_query('SELECT * FROM drupal_webform_component WHERE TYPE = "select" AND nid=123 ORDER BY weight');` generates results like this:

```
Select Option 1
Select Option 3
Select Option 4
Select Option 2
```

How do I order Webform results of components within fieldsets to reflect the order they appear on the form? What would the db_query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is a column `pid` in `webform_components` for individual components. This value correlates with the `cid` of the fieldset. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the `cid` and `pid` columns, filtered by the webform node id - `nid`, then ordered by the fieldset `weight` followed by the select option `weight` returns the components in the correct order as they appear on the node form. Here is the db_query statement.

```
db_query('SELECT *
FROM webform_component AS f
LEFT OUTER JOIN webform_component AS s ON f.cid = s.pid
WHERE f.nid = 123 AND s.nid = 123 AND f.type = "fieldset" AND s.type = "select"
ORDER BY f.weight, s.weight');
```

This works. Any advice on optimizing this query is appreciated.